# Go panics when too many goroutines querying MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, go, asynchronous, goroutine

I want to run separate goroutines that would work with a MySQL database. I wrote the code and it does work if the amount of goroutines is less than a 1000. But than I change it to a 1000, Go starts to panic.

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "time"
)

func routine(db *sql.DB, id int, ch chan<- string) {
    update, _ := db.Prepare("SELECT salary FROM users WHERE id = (?)")
    defer update.Close()
    var salary string
    update.QueryRow(id).Scan(&salary)
    ch <- salary
}

func main() {
    n := 1000

    ch := make(chan string)
    list := make([]string, n)

    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@/database")
    db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Minute * 3)
    defer db.Close()

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go routine(db, 123, ch)
    }
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        list[i] = <-ch
    }
}
```

And here's the error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

goroutine 948 [running]:
database/sql.(*Stmt).Close(0x0)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2872 +0x37
panic({0x4e8b20, 0x689240})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
database/sql.(*Stmt).QueryContext(0x0, {0x5788e8, 0xc000018050}, {0xc000d5bf60, 0x1, 0x1})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2767 +0x82
database/sql.(*Stmt).QueryRowContext(0x0?, {0x5788e8?, 0xc000018050?}, {0xc000d5bf60?, 0x27?, 0x0?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2845 +0x2c
database/sql.(*Stmt).QueryRow(...)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2867
main.routine(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        C:/Users/me/Desktop/go/5. MySQL/main.go:13 +0xfb
created by main.main
        C:/Users/me/Desktop/go/5. MySQL/main.go:28 +0xba
```

I'm not really sure what is the reason of this error. The code does work with less goroutines. In addition, I tried to use SQLite adapter, and 1000 goroutines worked just fine. But 1000 in MySQL is not.

Could you please describe how to get rid of these panics and make 1000 or even 10 thousands of goroutines work with the database?

---

My Go version is 1.18.3 windows/amd64
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql - v1.6.0

Comment: not super familiar with go; does it throw an exception if the Open fails, or just return nil?  if it returns nil, does db.SetConnMaxLifetime give that error when db is nil?  you may just need to reconfigure your mysql server to accept more connections

Comment: If Prepare returns an error, update is nil. Don't ignore the error. Same for Scan and sql.Open.

Comment: Where exactly does the panic occur? As mentioned, you're explicitly ignoring error values from key functions that would likely provide the info you need.

Comment: The errors from `Prepare` and `Open` are `nil`. The error occurs in somewhere in defer, as I understand. I updated the error message

Comment: Since the error is occurring in the standard library code, what version of Go are you using? The error is referenced by line number so we need to know we are looking at the same code.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco, it's 1.18.3 windows/amd64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your errors, don't ignore them. For example...

```
update, _ := db.Prepare("SELECT salary FROM users WHERE id = (?)")
```

The second value returned from `db.Prepare` is an [`error`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#error) which will explain what went wrong, but you're ignoring it. If `prepare` fails, `update` will be corrupted. When you try to use it in `update.QueryRow(id).Scan(&salary)` or `defer update.Close()` you get a panic.

Check the error and deal with it. In this case, print it and return.

```
update, err := db.Prepare("SELECT salary FROM users WHERE id = (?)")
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("db.Prepare failed:", err)
  return
}

// This has to come afterwards else you'll try to close nil.
defer update.Close()
```

Do this for everything which can return an error. That means `db.Prepare`, `sql.Open`, and [`Row.Scan`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Row.Scan).

See also [Errors and Exception Handling in Golang](https://golangdocs.com/errors-exception-handling-in-golang).

---

Note: MySQL has [a maximum number of prepared statements at one time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_prepared_stmt_count). If this is set low, for example 1024, that could be the problem. But the error should tell you.

Note: Preparing, executing, and closing the same statement over and over defeats the point of prepared statements. In a real application you'd prepare the statement once and pass it into each Goroutine. You'd only close the statement once all Goroutines are complete.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But there's no solution in your answer. I want to do 1000 goroutines and want all of them to work. If there's a maximum number I expect them to wait until they can connect

Comment: @Yoskutik, you cannot prevent any and all errors. You _must_ handle it, possibly by retrying, but without knowing the actual problem no one here can help you further. If the problem is exceeding the maximum number of prepared statements then the answer _does_ include a solution for the problem.

Comment: Hm. Yeah, now I understand. There were a few problems. I've replaced `Prepare` with a `Query` and configured max connections and max connection lifetime. And now its work

Answer (score 1):

Given this code...

```
update, _ := db.Prepare("SELECT salary FROM users WHERE id = (?)")
defer update.Close()
```

When `db.Prepare` returns an error, `update` will be `nil`*. You then attempt to call `nil.Close()`, yielding your error.

Don't blindly call `Close` on a nil object.

---

* This is not obvious from reading the documentation, but it's clear from the implementation (which ultimately lands on [this line](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.4:src/database/sql/sql.go;l=1588;drc=dc00aed6de101700fd02b30f93789b9e9e1fe9a1)) that when the returned error is *not* `nil`, the `*Stmt` will be `nil`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But there's no solution in your answer. I want to do 1000 goroutines and want all of them to work. If there's a maximum number I expect them to wait until they can connect

Comment: @Yoskutik Of course there is a maximum, no resource in any computer is infinite. If you want the connection to retry, you have to write that logic into your code. Whatever the problem actually is, you'll find it if you start checking errors rather than ignoring them, and that will inform your next steps in handling that error.